# selenium webdriver select element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a select control on my site.  I am using page objects to interact with the page.  If I do (with the first 2 lines under my class and the `selectByValue` in my method)

```java
@FindBy(id="foo")
private Select foo;

foo.selectByValue("myValue");
```

It fails with a null pointer.  I also tried without the `@FindBy`.

Now if I do this in my method it all works fine and selects the correct item

```java
Select foo = new Select(sDriver.findElement(By.id("foo")));
foo.selectByValue("myValue");
```

Here is the actual web snippet for that control (edited to protect the innocent)

```html
<select id="foo" name="service_name">
    <option selected="selected" value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
</select>
```

Let me say that I have a work around for my issue **but** I don't get why the "*normal*" path is not working.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Thats because the `Select` class has this constructor:

```
Select(WebElement element)
```

See the [Javadoc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html)

So if you do something like this:

```java
@FindBy(id="foo")
private WebElement wannabeSelect;
Select realSelect = new Select(wannabeSelect);
realSelect.selectByValue("myValue");
```

It should work.

BTW, I am using the same approach as you in the "workaround" because I dont wanna cast new WebElement object when I need Select object. But anyways, the

```java
sDriver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
```

returns `WebElement`, so thats why its working. You can also do this:

```java
 WebElement wannabeSelect = sDriver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
 Select foo = new Select(wannabeSelect);
```

Comment: ahh that makes sense it just seemed like it should have worked so I never really dug to deep.  My fault.  Thank you

Comment: Note: if you include the Select declaration and cast in your class, just below the private WebElement declaration, you will get runtime errors when the class is instantiated; to avoid this, you can put the Select declaration and class in the method which does the interaction with the screen control. Again not ideal, but it does seem to work.

Comment: with this approach, the pageobjects should be initialized after the page has fully loaded and that the object is present and visible in the driver. To have it proxied, take a look at [my implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931667/select-object-on-seleniums-pagefactory/36004572#36004572)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to select the option value:

One:

```
// Denotes option value - technical name
select.selectByValue(fieldValue);
```

Two:

```
// Denotes option text that is actually visible to be selected
select.selectByVisibleText(fieldValue);
```

Comment: and select.selectByIndex(intValue)

Answer (score 1):

Other way I achieved this is by using below method for all my onchange dropdownselection boxes. Pass id and selection and it works

```
public void onchangedropdownselection(String object, String value) {
        WebElement obj = driver.findElement(By.id(object));
        obj.sendKeys(value);
        obj.sendKeys(Keys.UP);
        obj.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
    }
```

By doing up and down we are initialzing the script onchange.......