# Selenium webdriverJS selectByIndex() Method

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find out the JavaScript equivalent of the selectByIndex() method that is provided in the Java Webdriver API. I am trying to do what is addressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138761/how-to-select-a-dropdown-value-in-selenium-webdriver) (but using the WebdriverJS framework):

I have looked at the [WebdriverJS source](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js), but haven't found anything.

Is there a way to select an element based off of its index position using Selenium's Javascript Webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

```
var index = {your in index}
driver.findElements(By.css('option'))
    .then(function(options){
        return options[index].click();
    });
```