# Unable to click on button and select element from dropdown list using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to click on the find button to get address list for that I have used `className` to find element but it is not working.

Code I have written.

```
driver.findElement(By.className("secondary right postfix findaddress")).click();
```

I have also tried using below code but it is not working. I am getting Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.className: secondary right postfix findaddress

```
WebDriverWait wait4 = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
WebElement radio4 = wait4.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("secondary right postfix findaddress")));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", radio4);
```

HTML code

```
<div class="small-3 columns">

<button class="secondary right postfix findaddress" style="border-left-color: currentColor !important; border-left-width: medium !important; border-left-style: none !important;" onclick="cmss.addressLookup.search($(this).closest('div.addressSearch'))" type="button">Find</button>

</div>
```

Once find button clicked select address from dropdown list.

```
<select class="AddressList" id="CurrentCriteria__addressLst">
<option>- Select -</option><option id="0" name="0">   I can't see my address    </option>
<option id="1" name="1"> 2  Abbot Gardens Essex IG5 7BB</option>
<option id="2" name="2"> 3  Abbot Gardens Essex IG5 7BB </option>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `By.className` does not support compound class, Try using `By.cssSelector` as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.secondary.right.postfix.findaddress")).click();
```

Comment: Code for button clicked is working fine. Can you please give me solution on how to select element from dropdown. I have updated the question.

Comment: @PrashantBellale [Have look on this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138761/how-to-select-a-dropdown-value-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java) to select value from dropdown

Comment: @SubhashGaur   This what I have written  `Select currentaddresslist = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("CurrentCriteria__addressLst")));  
        currentaddresslist.selectByVisibleText("2  Abbot Gardens Essex IG5 7BB"); ` but address is not getting selected.

Comment: @PrashantBellale in your dropdown options text lot of extra white spaces presents may be that's why your are in trouble try using `currentaddresslist.selectByIndex(2);`..Hope it works..:)

Answer (score 0):

You have used the locator `By.className("secondary right postfix findaddress")`, `className` locator can only be used if there is only `1` class.

Here in your case there are total `4` different classes, hence the locator that you have used wouldn't work.

You can go ahead with any of the below locator:-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.secondary.right.postfix.findaddress")).click();
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='secondary right postfix findaddress']")).click();
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/button")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type = 'button' and contains(@class,'secondary right postfix findaddress') and contains(text(), 'Find')]"))
```