# What are the ways available to handle a changing web element id and xpath

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

I created XPath for a dynamic web element and it found 2 very identical nodes.The XPath is://*[contains(@id, "gwt-uid-")]/span[2]. I have done everything possible to differentiate uniquely between the two nodes but no luck. The HTML is attached  Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: first, identify the nearest static element and then move to the element you required using XPath using XPATH Axes to traverse among HTML elements.

Comment: Ideally, use other stable attributes or a combination of them to ensure that it works. You'd be able to get specific help with the element if you include a snippet of your HTML in the question.

Comment: Could you share relevant HTML with 2-3 level above HTML??

Comment: @ Saurabh Gaur, @Sai please refer to the attached html above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. To macth first value (**Example** -> text in span tag):

   //div[contains(@id, 'gwt-uid-') and @aria-level="**1**"]/div/div/span[2]
2. To match second value (**Example1** -> text in span tag)

   //div[contains(@id, 'gwt-uid-') and @aria-level="**2**"]/div/div/span[2]

try the following XPath to match partial id:

```
//input[contains(@id, 'gwt-uid-')]
```

Comment: Naveen, well done! The the XPath you supplied worked. First please a give details of how the xpath was generated so I can handle similar scenarios in future. Second, the xpath did identify the web element I was looking for which is a dropdown element. When webdriver clicked on the dropdown the embedded items were displayed. Now, I do I choose one of the items. The all have html span tags like :<span>Shoe</span> and the xpath looks like this: .//*[@id='VAADIN_COMBOBOX_OPTIONLIST']/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/span

Comment: contains is a partial string matching method available in XPATH. I would suggest you go through the following link to fully understand what you can do with XPATH, http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp (all links under XPATH tutorial) and use Firebug and Firepath plugins (available to Firefox browser) to instantly check whether your XPath is working or not.

Comment: Naveen,following the scenario above, how do I select a dropdown item?

Comment: Always try to get the unique combination to match an element using XPATH using the element HTML code itself (using tag, attributes, text etc). For selecting one element one way is to click on one element from list of elements from the dropdown menu. that you can achieve by finding one of the values from the dropdown list as follows <identify parent tag of all the values>/use index to match one element. PLEASE SHARE HTML CODE containing list of elements & its parents (2-3 levels)

Comment: see the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138761/how-to-select-a-dropdown-value-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: you can try out the methods which suits your needs best: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#corelib

Comment: Look at this changing xpath whose ID similar to above is dynamic as the number keeps changing. Will "contains" work in this case? .//*[@id='gwt-uid-361']/span[2]

Comment: Yes, Definitely! Use //*[contains(@id, "gwt-uid-")]/span[2] (Use tag instead of * to get more unique)

Comment: you used an input tag instead of div. I tried the "input" and as expected, it did not work, so I changed it to "div" and banged, it worked like a charm. You did really well with this XPath. Thank you.

Comment: yeah. I forgot to edit that ;-). edited now. thanks for the correction.

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290308/xpath-matching-one-node-not-working-in-webdriver