# Xpath matching one node but not working in webdriver

Tags: eclipse, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Is it normal for an XPath that was validated correctly in firepath and matched 1 node to fail to work in selenium webdriver (java)? I have a dynamic element and I have generated an XPath using the "contains" method which matched a single node that happens to be the same element I was looking for. In eclipse, webdriver throws a "NoSuchElementException" as it was unable to find the element. After you think you have mastered the tricks behind Xpath, some stubborn webelements uncover your flaws.

For the attached html, I have generated the below Xpath. Can anyone help generate an XPath or even CSS that would work?

```
//div[contains(@id, 'gwt-uid') and @aria-selected='true']
```

[image]

Comment: Share HTML code, not in image format but as part of your question text (use {} in format bar, to highlight the HTML). This will help us to evaluate your XPATH against HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There is always a possibility of XPATH matching using Firebug (during development mode, where you visited page manually) may not identify during run time (browser launched using selenium). It is not because of Firebug showing wrong, but the HTML against which XPATH is using, may not be the same (might have changed, may be subtle changes).

I would strongly suggest **pause** (not stopping it) the execution during the run-time (one way is, using Thread.sleep(100) (100 seconds)) to give you enough time to evaluate your XPATH again to see the matches. post your observations.

XPATH seems fine to me.

Suspect may be, `aria-selected` set to `false`

Comment: the maximum time I waited in this case was 10s. 100s sounds outrageous as I have never had to put a page or action to sleep for this long, but I can try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I told keep 100 seconds only for debugging. Once you validated the XPath during run-time, change it to original. What are your observations during run-time? XPATH matching the element?

Comment: yes XPATH matches the element during run-time. It only fails to work in webdriver as webdriver insists that it cannot find the element, even after a wait time.

Answer (score 1):

I would think finding `By.CssSelector` would be easier:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[id^='gwt-uid']"));
```

Though I would be concerned there may be other elements with ids prefixed with 'gwt-uid' because of what I assume is a dynamic unique id at the end of it. You could get the known closest parent (`id='consumerTree'`) first to ensure you don't end up getting the wrong element. In C#:

```
IWebElement parent = driver.FindElement(By.Id("consumerTree"));
IWebElement element = parent.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[id^='gwt-uid']"));
```

Comment: What is so different that's throwing you off? I know casing differences, like lower case c in cssSelector... Is it that I don't use . notation? It works in Java and C#, save for minor syntax differences like I noted.

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362992/cssselector-needed-to-match-one-node

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming you're using Java) If you are getting `NoSuchElementException` as your provided exception, There may be following reasons :-

- May be when you are going to find element, it would not be present on the `DOM`, So you should implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until element visible as below :-

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div#consumerTree div.v-tree-node[id*='gwt-uid']")));
  ```
- May be this element is inside any `frame` or `iframe`. If it is, you need to switch that `frame` or `iframe` before finding the element as below :-

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

  //Find frame or iframe and switch
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("your frame id or name"));

  //Now find the element 
  WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div#consumerTree div.v-tree-node[id*='gwt-uid']")));

  //Once all your stuff done with this frame need to switch back to default
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  ```

Comment: great, your cssSelector worked: div#consumerTree div.v-tree-node[id*='gwt-uid']. It worked out of the box without using the wait command you suggested.

Comment: cssSelector seems to be showing superiority over XPath and it's worth learning the various cssSelector syntaxes for battling dynamic elements. But, How can we easily identify when to use cssSelector over Xpath or is just a case of trial and error to find out which would execute?

Comment: good to see it is working for you. accept the answer. Always prefer CSSSelector over XPath. only way to learn anything is by practicing it. here is the link for CSS selectors http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: @Naveen, thank you. I shall explore the information on the link

Comment: @Naveen, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40411987/web-element-skipped-in-ie-webdriver