# how to select element by value from dropdown with java & selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, web

am trying to select country code from dropdown where the elements has no index or ID i can only select by value, i tried using SelectByValue & VisibleText Both didnt work also tried to list element and loop on them but didnt work either

**Update:**
it gives me error: `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been “select” but was “button”`

how can i select from button with list of elements ??

here is the code:

```
public void selectInDropDownMenuCountryCode(final WebDriver driver, final By selector, final String selection) {
    _wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(selector));
    final Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(selector));
    //select.selectByVisibleText(selection);
    //select.selectByValue(selection);
     String code;

      List<WebElement> optionsD = select.getOptions();

    for (WebElement option : optionsD) {
         code = option.getAttribute("value");
        if (code == selection) {
            option.click();
            break;
        }       

    }
}
```

Screenshot of html
[image: here is the html code]

Comment: Show exact selectors you used

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select a dropdown value in Selenium WebDriver using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138761/how-to-select-a-dropdown-value-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use simple `click()` method to select required drop-down option:

```
_wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Egypt (+20)')]"))).click();
```

`XPath` like `"//a[@country='Egypt']"` or `"//a[@value='EG']"` seem to be applicable also

Note that you should click on appropriate element to open drop-down before clicking on its option

Answer (score 0):

If you refer the `HTML` you can see the `Dropdown` isn't built using `HTML Select` tag. So you can't use the below methods:-

1. selectByValue
2. selectByIndex
3. selectByVisibleText

You have to identify the elements using regular methods to handle dropdown. e.g: Try clicking on dropdown by identifying the element and then again click on the country name to select the value.