# "No SuchElementException was unhandled" exception in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("navHHome")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Canon")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("searchBrand")).SendKeys("Canon AP" + Keys.Enter);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("pListSearch")).SendKeys("AP 01" + Keys.Enter);
```

HTML:

              Druckerzubehör

```
            <li><a itemprop="url" href="/canon/default.aspx">Canon</a></li>
```

I am getting an error No SuchElementException was unhandled                                                An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: Unable to locate element: #searchBrand

Could any one tell me if this is rightly coded?

Thanks

Comment: Please format your code for proper viewing and share the relevant HTML DOM.

Comment: basically my doubt is i want to select a item from dropdown box and then select the items by search

Comment: Please add the error you see, that will help a lot to help you

Comment: Provide more info and update the Question as: 1. What is your exact testing steps? 2. What worked for you? Show code. 3. Where are you stuck? 4. Provide error stacktrace. 5. Provide relevant HTML DOM.

Comment: @Gulshan Update your question, dont put html/errors/code in comments.

Comment: Its quite clear: Unable to locate element: #searchBrand and from your HTML snippet there is no element with an id of searchBrand

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to select a `select` option value, which has its particularities. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138761/how-to-select-a-dropdown-value-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java), may help.

Answer (score 2):

this code is looking for an id named "searchBrand":

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("searchBrand"))
```

here is the HTML snippet you posted:

```
<li><a itemprop="url" href="/canon/default.aspx">Canon</a></li>
```

Do you see an element there with an id named "searchBrand"?  Do you see any id's at all?  I certainly don't.

When you search for an element that can't be found, it will throw a `NoSuchElementException`... that's the way it works.