# How can i select random elements from dropdown lists which has tagname as <div>?

Tags: java, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138761/how-to-select-a-dropdown-value-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)** thing and it works perfectly when the tag name is selected, but when I use `Select select = new Select();` in the tag name `div`, or something, it fails to work and prompts me with the following error:  **`org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "div"`**.

```
<div stop-propagation="click" class="custom-select-search">
    <input class="undefined ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" type="text" autocomplete="off" ng-model="searchTerm">
</div> 
<ul role="menu">
    <li role="presentation" class="ng-scope">
        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href=""ng-click="select(s)" class="ng-binding">166</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="ng-scope">
        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href=""ng-click="select(s)" class="ng-binding">164</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="ng-scope">
        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href=""ng-click="select(s)" class="ng-binding">165</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="ng-scope">
        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href=""ng-click="select(s)" class="ng-binding">166</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is my code:

```
        WebElement elements = driver.findElement(serial);
        Select ComboBoxValues = new Select(elements);
        List <WebElement> weblist = ComboBoxValues.getOptions();
        int iCnt = weblist.size();
        Random num = new Random();
        int iSelect = num.nextInt(iCnt);
        ComboBoxValues.selectByIndex(iSelect);
        System.out.println("Element Name 1 : " +elements.getAttribute("value"));
```

Can anyone tell me to do this.

Comment: Can you post your code and html from where element has to be picked. It would be quick to respond with suggestion.

Comment: I have added my code  and html code above.

Comment: As it is not a select tag hence Select ComboBoxValues = new Select(elements); is not working

Comment: @User Surely it's not a normal Dropdown, my guess its a modal dropdown where using `Select` class won't work. The line `WebElement elements = driver.findElement(serial);` doesn't looks meaningful to me. Can you consider showing a bit more of the HTML DOM? Thanks

Comment: I just want to know, if there is a dropdown list with a different tag name except select tagname then how can i write selenium script for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the site has some custom UI that emulates a dropdown.  Which means you'll have to implement your own code to interact with it.  I would recommend creating a class, let's call it MySiteSelector, that will have a select() method which knows where to click to open the menu list (it doesn't look like that's here), then will search through your list items (a css selector would be "ul[role='menu] li") to find the one that matches your desired target.

Answer (score 0):

As per selenium **select** documentation,

***Open Declaration org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select

***Models a SELECT tag, providing helper methods to select and deselect options.***

which mean SELECT can be used for drop-downs with **select tag only**. You applications drop-downs are made using DIV tag. that's the reason your code doesn't works on your web page

Comment: How can i do this thing with DIV tagname