# How to select an option from the dropdown as per the HTML through Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

This is My HTML:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;padding-bottom:10px;">You     have Statewide Access<br>Please select the district in which you want to    operate</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td style="text-align:right;width:50%;font-weight:bold;padding-right:10px;"><label      for="districtOption">Select District</label></td>
    <td style="text-align:left;width:50%;">
      <select id=`district Option` name="district Option" size="0"                  alt="Select District" tab index="1">
        <option value="00" selected="">-- SELECT --</option>
        <option value="01"> A1 </option>
        <option value="02"> A2 </option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

My First Try:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='distrctOption']")));
select.selectByVisibleText("A1");
```

Second Try:

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("districtOption")));
dropdown.selectByIndex(01);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@value='Select']")).click();
```

Error Message in Console
for every executing one Error "Exception in thread "main"

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException Unable to locate element"

*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//select[@id='districtOption']}
```

I tried all possible ways i can ?

There are no Frames in Page, but still not able to Select it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select a dropdown value in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138761/how-to-select-a-dropdown-value-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Comment: It's `district Option`, not `districtOption`. Spaces are important.

Comment: Are you sure that the _value_ of `id` attribute contains the two backticks i.e. **`** ?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='district Option']")));
```

You are missing the space in your xpath identification.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared to select an option from the dropdown you have to use the `<select>`class and the associated methods and you can use either of the following solutions:

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[name='district Option'][alt='Select District']")));
//Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='district Option' and @alt='Select District']")));
dropdown.selectByValue("01"); //to select the option A1
dropdown.selectByValue("02"); //to select the option A2
```