# Select from combo box using selenium webdriver without select statement

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
Html:
<input size="24" autocomplete="off" id="P.Gender" name="P.Gender" class=" x-form-text x-form-field x-form-focus" style="width: 125px;" title="" type="text">

<div class="x-layer x-combo-list " id="ext-gen1943" style="position: absolute; z-index: 11000; visibility: visible; left: 377px; top: 232px; width: 148px; height: 60px; font-size: 12px;">
<div class="x-combo-list-inner" id="ext-gen1944" style="width: 148px; height: 60px;">
<div class="x-combo-list-item ">Unknown</div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item ">Male</div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item  x-combo-selected">Female</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Question: How to select Male/Female/Unknown from above HTML using Selenium webdriver? There is no select class in HTML, so I am not able to use Select.

Comment: The description of tag selenium-webdriver says: *When using this tag, also add a tag for the programming language you are using*, so please do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select a dropdown value in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138761/how-to-select-a-dropdown-value-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Comment: @GabrielDevillers That's not an actual SELECT element... it's just designed to look like one so your dup doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can normally use xpath with contains for selecting male/female/unknowm. Otherwise you can ask your developers to add select tag for these dropdowns if they can make the changes.

Example: //div[contains(text(),'Male')]