# StaleElementReferenceException: element is not attached to the page document while selecting the options from multiple Dropdowns using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, dropdown, webdriverwait, staleelementreferenceexception

Code trial:

```
#coding=utf-8

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pandas as pd 

# Below is to crawl data from a webpage with two different dropdown
try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')


    driver.get('https://price.joinsland.joins.com/theme/index_theme.asp?sisaegbn=T05')

    select1 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='sido']"))))
    for item1 in select1.options:
        item1.click()
        select2 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='gugun']"))))
        for item2 in select2.options:
            item2.click()
            time.sleep(2)

            # below is to get the attained date into excel file
            table = driver.find_element_by_class_name('tbl_box')
            tbody = table.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')
            rows=tbody.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')


            total = []
            result = []
            for index, value in enumerate(rows):
                body = value.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')

                for i in range(len(body)):
                    data = body[i].text
                    result.append(data)

            total.append(result)
            result=[]

        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(total)
        df.to_excel('text.xlsx')



except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

I have edited this code thanks to the lovely comment below but I get the same error saying as below.:

```
Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

I roughly understand why this message shows up but still have no clear idea on how to fix this. I would deeply appreciate any comment! Many thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: This helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20140481/9011164 ?

Comment: still having a hard time understanding the post you mentioned. Any idea how to fix the code?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know python. You don't have to click on `option` from `select`. In Selenium you have the object `Select` which is special for `select` tag in html. It helps you to choose the option. Here is another link with python: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms . Maybe this one helps. I will try to provide an answer but have not knowledge about python.

Comment: Thanks a lot KunLun! The link you shared helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I figured out. But I'm not sure if code is right or not. I don't know python.

```
#get select
select1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@name="sido"]'))

#get all options from select
options1 = select1.options

for opt1 is options1:

    #select the option which has the value of opt1
    select1.select_by_value(opt1.get_attribute("value"))
    time.sleep(5)

    select2 = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@name="gugu"]'))
    options2 = select2.options

    for opt2 in options2:
        select1.select_by_value(opt2.get_attribute("value"))
        time.sleep(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

To select all the `<option>` elements from multiple e.g. two (2) different [drop-down-select](/questions/tagged/drop-down-select) elements within the website https://price.joinsland.joins.com/theme/index_theme.asp?sisaegbn=T05 you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
driver.get('https://price.joinsland.joins.com/theme/index_theme.asp?sisaegbn=T05')
select1 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='sido']"))))
for item1 in select1.options:
    item1.click()
    select2 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='gugun']"))))
    for item2 in select2.options:
        item2.click()
        time.sleep(3) # perform your web-crawling here
```

Comment: A million thanks to you! Your code seems to be working well in the beginning but I still get the same error. You may know how to fix this again..?

Comment: oh thanks! still getting used to this website! Thanks for sharing!