# Select from dropdown in selenium-webdriver javascript

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to select a value from drop down using selenium-webdriver JavaScript bindings. I do see that Select is available in Java. I have seen similar option in C# also. Couldn't find anything in JavaCcript to handle select option [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138761/how-to-select-a-dropdown-value-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In selenium-webdriver JavaScript you don't have "Select" class. You just need to simply click on drop-down option by passing correct css/xpath.

```
let element = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css(cssLocator)));
element.click();
```