# How to use selenium on websites which use ajax?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have tried using selenium to automate a website and select a option from the drop-down menu, but the problem I am facing is that after the option is selected the ajax is not executed. This only happens when using **selenium**, I had tried this manually and it worked. Webdriver wait is not working for me. Here is the code that does that:

```
WebElement element =(driver.findElement(By.id("equity_optionchain_select")));
    Select elementSelect=new Select(element);
    elementSelect.selectByVisibleText("BANKNIFTY");
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138761/how-to-select-a-dropdown-value-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: @Verity my question is i am able to select the value from that drop-down menu but the ajax is not executed or the dom is not changed so i am not able to see the differences after selecting the value,the differences are visible when i use the website without selenium which means the dom changes  ,i want it to change the dom when selenium is used.

Answer (score 0):

As far as *BANKNIFTY* is concerned, presumably those elements will be dynamic elements i.e. either [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/), [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/), [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp), [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/), [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/), [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/overview.html), etc. based elements. So ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *id* and `selectByVisibleText()`:

  ```
  new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("equity_optionchain_select")))).selectByVisibleText("BANKNIFTY");
  ```
- Using *cssSelector* and `selectByVisibleText()`:

  ```
  new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#equity_optionchain_select")))).selectByVisibleText("BANKNIFTY");
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `selectByVisibleText()`:

  ```
  new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='equity_optionchain_select']")))).selectByValue("BANKNIFTY");
  ```