# How to select an option from a dynamic drop down using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, html

[Drop Down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2TFC.png) I am trying to click on drop down value to select city in from field in dropdownMenuButton
goToConfiguration my code is like this and I need to do it in automation code.

Go to Configuration

Comment: You can access it using its index from a NodeList.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select a dropdown value in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138761/how-to-select-a-dropdown-value-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.