# Select object on selenium's PageFactory

Tags: java, selenium

I know that you cannot initialize a `Select` object in `PageFactory`.
I have been searching on the internet and have found only one possible answer, to use `ElementLocatorFactory` but did not have much details on the implementation.
Im asking if their is someone who successfully implemented it or has idea on implementing it, im okay with other ways than `ElementLocatorFactory`.

Currently, Im only using something like this:

```
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "select-log-status")
public WebElement __logStatus;
public Select selectLogStatus() {
    return new Select(__logStatus);
}
```

What im looking for to implement is something like this.

```
@FindSelectBy(how = How.ID, using = "select-log-status")
public Select selectLogStatus;
```

PS. Im new to selenium and a returning java developer, so please treat me well :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since nobody shared something, I will share how I did it.

I looked into the code and found out that its the object type is being filtered in `DefaultFieldDecorator`'s `decorate` method, so what I did was simply created a custom FieldDecorator and extended the `DefaultFieldDecorator` class because I only wanted to override the `decorate`.

So, I have a PageObject class `MyPageObjects`

```
public class MyPageObjects {
    protected final WebDriver driver;
    public MyPageObjects (WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }


    @FindBy(id = "my-select-object")
    public Select mySelectObj;
}
```

My CustomFieldDecorator would contain this overriden method:

```
@Override
public Object decorate(ClassLoader loader, Field field) {
    if (!(WebElement.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())
        || Select.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())
        || List.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())
        || isDecoratableList(field))) {
      return null;
    }

    ElementLocator locator = factory.createLocator(field);
    if (locator == null) {
      return null;
    }

    if (WebElement.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
      return proxyForLocator(loader, locator);
    } else if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
          return proxyForListLocator(loader, locator);
    } else if (Select.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
          return new Select(locator.findElement());
    } else {
      return null;
    }
}
```

Notice the lines:

```
|| Select.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())
```

and

```
} else if (Select.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
      return new Select(locator.findElement());
```

---

I would initElements like this...

```
MyPageObjects page = new MyPageObjects(driver);
PageFactory.initElements(new CustomFieldDecorator(
    new DefaultElementLocatorFactory(driver), page);
```

And access the Select object as usual...

```
page.mySelectObj.selectByVisibleText("hello world");
```

**Caveat** : This does not use `Proxy`, so be careful. And the `WebElement` Select class wrapped is cached.

---

**UPDATE:**

I Created a proxy handler for `Select`. I created a class extending `Select` and an interface having `Select`'s methods.

`CustomSelect.java`

```
public class CustomSelect extends Select implements SelectInput {
    public CustomSelect(WebElement element) {
        super(element);
    }
}
```

`SelectInput.java` -- Interface

```
public interface SelectInput {
    boolean isMultiple();
    List<WebElement> getOptions();
    List<WebElement> getAllSelectedOptions();
    WebElement getFirstSelectedOption();
    void selectByVisibleText(String text);
    void selectByIndex(int index);
    void selectByValue(String value);
    void deselectAll();
    void deselectByValue(String value);
    void deselectByIndex(int index);
    void deselectByVisibleText(String text);
}
```

`SelectElementHanlder.java` -- InvocationHandler

```
public class SelectElementWrapperHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private final ElementLocator locator;

    public SelectElementWrapperHandler(ElementLocator locator) {
        this.locator = locator;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        CustomSelect element;
        try {
            element = new CustomSelect(locator.findElement());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if ("toString".equals(method.getName())) {
                return "Proxy select(element) for: " + locator.toString();
            }
            else throw e;
        }

        try {
            return method.invoke(element, args);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw e.getCause();
        }

    }

}
```

Created a method in CustomFieldDecorator

```
protected SelectInput proxySelectForLocator(ClassLoader loader, ElementLocator locator) {
        InvocationHandler handler = new SelectElementWrapperHandler(locator);

        SelectInput proxy;
        proxy = (SelectInput) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            loader, new Class[]{SelectInput.class}, handler);
        return proxy;
    }
```

And changing this line from the CustomFieldDecorator

```
} else if (Select.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
          return new Select(locator.findElement());
```

to this:

```
} else if (SelectInput.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
              return proxySelectForLocator(loader, locator);
```

Now, I would declare the select object in my PageObject class like:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "some..xpath")
public SelectInput ticketStatus;
```

---

Hope It helps. Please modify if have corrections :)

Comment: Do you have this saved in a git repo or something? I'd like to take a look at it as a whole

Comment: @GabrieleB-David it is inside our internal git repo. But that's basically it. You can also check selenium's docs as it is very helpful.

Comment: Also you have to replace `|| Select.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())` with `|| SelectInput.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())`

Comment: This is my implementation, is someone wants to see https://gist.github.com/iamandrewluca/b7180b8fa2d84e6f046f167d0ec1e58e

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you can initialize a Select element in the class constructor or where the driver is being initialized.

```
Select dropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(locator));
```

Comment: thank you for your answer @Haxor , yes this is correct. But in my question I am using `PageFactory` to initialize my page objects. But the `PageFactory` only initializes `WebElements` not `Select` objects.

Answer (score 0):

**Declare as WebElement**

```
@FindBy(xpath = ".//span[text()='Country Located*']/parent::div/parent::div//select")
private WebElement select_Country;
```

**Initialization of Element:**

```
public Constructor(WebDriver driver) {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
    this.interactions = new Interactions(driver);
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
}
```

**Create Method to Wait and then cast to Select**

```
public void selectFromDropDown(WebElement element, String country) {
      try{
        if (wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)).isDisplayed()){
            Select select = new Select(element);
            select.selectByVisibleText(country);
        }
      }
    }
```

**Usage**

```
selectFromDropDown(select_Country,userDetails.getCountry());
```