# Selenium won't check a checkbox, how do I reference the checkbox correctly?

Tags: c#, checkbox, selenium-webdriver

I am having trouble making my Selenium-Webdriver script check Susie's checkbox.  I have tried using clicking and sending space keys, and also changing my xpaths.  Could someone please help me find a way of specifying that I need Susie's checkbox, and also help me click it?

### HTML on page

```
<tr class="dataRow">
    <td class="jtable-selecting-column">
         <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td class=" FirstName ">Laura</td>
    <td class=" LastName ">Test</td>
    <td class=" SMSNumber ">4444444444</td>
    </tr>
<tr class="dataRow">
    <td class="jtable-selecting-column">
         <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td class=" FirstName ">Susie</td>
    <td class=" LastName ">Test</td>
    <td class=" SMSNumber ">5555555555</td>
```

### my code

```
WebDriverWait waitPlease = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement myDynamicElement = waitPlease.Until<IWebElement>(d => d.FindElement(By.ClassName(" FirstName ")));
```

clickButtonWithXPath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/input");

### Error

reads "System.InvalidOperationException:unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (192,464). Other element would receive the click: ...

Comment: Would those work?  How much code would I need to add?

Comment: Okay thanks anyway

Comment: Look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604336/selenium-webdriver-select-element

Comment: <input type="checkbox"> I am assuming this is a type, with no end tag. Anyway can you try clicking on the td by class name = "jtable-selecting-column"?

Comment: Edit: I added the code I've been working with that has an explicit wait and then an xpath to the checkbox.

Comment: Update: It seems that the xpath technique probably works, but the scripts is not waiting long enough for the window that contains the checkbox to load.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the the XPath was working just fine, but the script wasn't waiting long enough.  Unfortunately, Thread.sleep(5000) is the only wait I've found that works effectively.

Edit: Thanks so much everyone! It turns out that using xpaths was a reliable way of referencing the checkbox, but Selenium needed to be instructed to wait before attempting to click it.
The best way to do this is with explicit wait. I used the code on [this](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) documentation page under "expected conditions".

Comment: you need to set up a wait; `Thread.Sleep` is a bit of a hack (I know you have used a wait above, but that's the route you need to make work, not the hacky way ;) )

Comment: Thanks! Explicit wait does work much better, I just had to change how I was using it.